# Mysqli not returning right elements

Tags: php, mysqli

So I came across another problem.

I have this piece of code:

```
    $query = mysqli_query($mysqli_connect,"
        SELECT profileCode
        FROM personprofile5
        WHERE profileId = '$url'
        LIMIT 30
    ");
    $sqlObject = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $output = $sqlObject['profileCode'];
    if(!empty($output)){
        echo count($sqlObject);
        echo '</br></br>';
        print_r($sqlObject);
    } else {
        echo 'This page does not exist.';
    }
```

The problem is that it should return 2 when echoing the count. And it does, but it's because there is a `$sqlObject[0]` and a `$sqlObject['profileCode']`(with the same results) which isn't the way it should be. 
I want my mysqly to return ALL the values in that column.

So who can help me?

Comment: Nothing personal but -1 for the old php-style: all SQL, PHP and HTML in one spaghetti bowl.

Comment: As for your problem - every time you have an idea that PHP function doesn't return the right value - **turn to this function's manual page**. Most likely you are using it wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you may use [`mysqli_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) with goods parameters. If you only want an associative array use `MYSQLI_ASSOC` constant as second parameter.

After if you want more than one result you should loop on `mysqli_fetch_array` or use [`mysqli_fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)